# Is this proof correct? (equality of unions)

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, set-theory

I have seen other proofs for this question and I know how to do them, but I wanted to see if my method is correct.

> Show that if $f:A \to B$ and $E, F \subseteq A$, then $f(E \cup F)= f(E) \cup f(F)$.

Let $x \in f(E \cup F) \implies f^{-1}(x) \in E \cup F \implies f^{-1}(x) \in E$ or $f^{-1}(x) \in F$

$\implies x \in f(E)$ or $x \in f(F) \implies x \in f(E) \cup f(F)$

I haven't finished the proof since i'm left with proving the other side, I just wanted to know if there is anything that I got confused?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by $f^{-1}(x)$? Your function is in general not injective.

Comment: @OliverHouse yes I know I just wanted to know if the proof is correct up until that point.

Comment: @Matthias I assumed that if x is element of a range of a function then the inverse would exist to.

Comment: "A preimage" exists for sure, an inverse of $f$ does not exist, in general. So better write something like "it exists a $y \in A$ with $f(y)=x$". This $y$ is not necessarily unique.

Comment: @Matthias I see. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: If $f$ is not injective then $f^{-1}(x)$ is the set $\{u\in E\cup F| f(u)=x\}$ and not a single element.  At this point you could say $f^{-1}(x) = \{u\in E|f(u)=x\}\cup \{u\in F|f(u)=x\}$.  And... well, I fear handwaving and circular arguments are in the future.  It *can* be salvaged but I don't think it's worth it and it lacks clarity.  .... A far better approach (IMAEEO) would be say: Let $x\in f(E\cup U)$; then there exists (at least one) $y\in E\cup U$ so that $f(y)=x$...(I think you trying to do that in the first place).

Comment: Actually I was mistaked.  $f^{-1}(x) = \{u\in A|f(u)=x\}$.  This can be many elements and *all* we can say about this set of possibly many elements is that at least *one* of them is in $E\cup F$ and all of them are such that $f(u)=x$.  I suppose you can try to say let $u_1$ be one of the elements in the set so that $u_1\in E\cup F$ but then it could proceed.

Comment: @fleablood Hmm.. I know 2 other proofs that work, I just wanted to check if this works at all but it seems like there are holes in my assumptions so thank you!

Comment: Well, it seems what what you really wanted to say was "$x\in f(E\cup F)$ and so there is a an element in $E\cup F$ that maps to $x$, we call that $something$"  That'd be fine if you just used proper terminology for what you know.   We can't assume that is $f^{-1}(x)$ because we don't know that $f^{-1}$ exists as an inverse function (and if we use $f^{-1}$ as the pre-image then it's not a single element).  But if we simply said "... Let's call it $y$" everything from there on would be totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be looking for feedback on your proof here I'll try to give you some. So as you wrote yourself, you only tried to prove that if $f:A\to B$ is a mapping, and $E,F\subseteq A$, then $f(E\cup F)\subseteq f(E)\cup f(F)$.

A major problem that breaks your argument is when you write that

$$x\in f(E\cup F)\implies f^{-1}(x)\in E\cup F.$$

Now as you probably have not spotted it yourself, we cannot even guarantee that $f^{-1}$ exists, and in most cases it does not. To have the existence of an inverse mapping $f^{-1}$ is equivalent to having that $f$ is bijective, and since so such assumptions have been made, we cannot assume $f^{-1}$ exists. Now to give you a clue on how you can actually proceed from here, recall the definition of the image of a subset $C\subseteq A$ under $f$, which states that

$$f(C) := \{ f(y)\in B : y \in C \},$$

i.e. $f(C)$ is the set of all $f(y)$ with $y\in C$. Now in your proof, this means that you have that

$$x\in f(E\cup F) \iff x=f(y) \text{ for some } y\in E\cup F.$$

I really encourage you to try to finish it for yourself from this point. If you still get stuck, I'll provide a proof in what follows. As another recommendation before I continue with my proof is to use more text, and not just write your proof in symbols. It will make it look nicer and be much more readable. **So try it first, and only after that have a look here.**

Let $x\in f(E\cup F)$. Then $x=f(y)$ for some $y\in E\cup F$. But then we also have that

$$y\in E \quad \text{or} \quad y\in F,$$
and so
$$f(y)\in f(E) \quad \text{or} \quad f(y)\in f(F).$$

By definition it follows that $x=f(y)\in f(E)\cup f(F)$. Thus, as $x$ was arbitrary, $f(E\cup F)\subseteq f(E)\cup f(F)$.

Comment: "we cannot even guarantee that f−1 exists"  I'd say in many text (if not most) $f^{-1}$ is not always defined as the inverse function but as the pre-image.  As the pre-image $f^{-1}(x) = \{u\in A| f(u) = x\}$ most certain does always exist (although it may be empty) but it is not a single element, so much as set possibly with many elements.  These elements that all map to $x$ don't need to all come from $E\cup F$ but at least one must.  But if we are to single that one element out there was no real reason we needed to look at the pre-image at all.

Comment: I'd strongly disagree here with you saying that $f^{-1}(x)$ reasonably denotes the pre-image. For that the notation $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is undoubtedly unambiguous in the pre-image of the set containing only $x$. Especially in the fact that OP wrote $f^{-1}(x)\in E\cup F$ and not $f^{-1}(x)\subseteq E\cup F$ strongly supports my assertion of it being the inverse in this case

Comment: I didn't mean the OPs intent, which is clearly the inverse function but with ... oh, I don't know.... the pre-image *is* very useful and frequently done in proofs of this sort.  You are right about the notation $\in$ though (I had noticed that and then dropped it).  Also $x\in f(E\cup F) \implies f^{-1}(x)\subset E\cup F$ is obviously false.... Never mind....

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets and $f:A\to B$ be any function. Let $E$ and $F$ be subsets of $A$. You are trying to show that $$f(E\cup F)\subseteq f(E)\cup f(F)$$ for the first half of your proof.

Let $y\in f(E\cup F)$. Then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in E\cup F$. If $x\in E$, then $$y=f(x)\in f(E)\subseteq f(E)\cup f(F).$$ Otherwise, $x\in F$ gives that $$y=f(x)\in f(F)\subseteq f(E)\cup f(F).$$ As you can see, there is no need for $f$ to be either injective or surjective here, and there is no need to use preimages. The other half of the proof is no harder.